# How to Crop Multiple Images

Tags: python, image, crop

I'm working on a project to crop 3000 images. I have created 3000 images using an algorithm, and am trying to crop them. Currently, they are all sitting in a folder with names that follow the same format - "img1", "img2", "img3" etc. I have tried using online tools to crop all of these images but it isn't working. I'm looking for an approach, whether using a free software to crop all of them at once or using python to crop these images and store them in a separate folder.

Comment: Why don't you do the same as when cropping one image, but in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small code to do that for you.

***pip install opencv-python***

```
import cv2 as cv
import os

#First get the list of images in the folder
list_of_original_images = os.listdir("images") #Add the path to the folder

#Create a new directory to store the cropped images
os.mkdir("Cropped_Images")

#Iterate through the image_list
for image_path in list_of_original_images:
    image_array = cv.imread(image_path) # Here we load image using opencv
    height,width,channel = image_array.shape #Here we get the height,width and color channel
    cropped_image = image_array[0:height//2,0:width//2] # Using array slicing we cut some part of the image and save in a new variable

    # Write cropped image to Cropped Images folder
    cv.write(f"Cropped_Images/{image_path}",cropped_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) library makes it quite easy:

```py
from PIL import Image;

DirectoryPath = r"C:\Users\...\FolderWithImages";
Images = GetFiles(DirectoryPath);

for Img in Images:
    BaseImg = Image.open(Img);
    
    #The arguments to .crop is a rect (X,Y,Width,Height)
    CroppedImg = im.crop((0,0,500,500))
     
    CroppedImg.save("Path");
```

To get all files in a directory you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

The example by BBonless works, but there is a misunderstanding about the im.crop parameters.  It is not Width and Height, but Right and Lower co-ordinates.  It only works if you want to crop from top-left.

My example below takes Top, Left, Width and Height and works out the Right and Lower positions from those.

It will prompt the user for a source directory and will save the cropped files in c:\temp.  It is easy to prompt for the output directory in the same way as the input directory using another fd.askdirectory() call.

```
import glob
import os
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

from PIL import Image

directory_path = fd.askdirectory()

Images = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path,"*.jpg"))

for image_file_and_path in Images:
    image_filename = os.path.basename(image_file_and_path)
    output_filename = os.path.join(r"c:\temp\cropped", image_filename)
    uncropped_image = Image.open(image_file_and_path)

    # The argument to crop is a box : a 4-tuple defining the left, upper, right, and lower pixel positions.
    left = 450
    top = 50
    width = 2595
    height = 3226

    CroppedImg = uncropped_image.crop((left, top, width + left, height + top))

    CroppedImg.save(output_filename)
```